# Difficulty in inserting HTML output table from R into Outlook

Tags: html, r, outlook

I created a HTML table in R using the package HTMLTable. However, the output generated from HTMLTable shows up terribly in Outlook. It's basically almost unreadable. The borders don't show up in Outlook at all, and spacing is far too large. I know the output from `R2HTML` works in Outlook, but as far as I know I can't get up the `<HTML></HTML>` tags to show up with `R2HTML`.

Help or advice would be much appreciated. Below is the current code I'm using to export my .html table:

```
htmltools::save_html(htmlTable::htmlTable(data), file = "data")
```

Comment: By what do you mean "Outlook"? Is that the E-mail client when you send the e-mail? As far as I know, e-mails support only rudimentary html. Have you tried other clients? In my book, Microsoft internet products  don't play well with the rest of the world.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Sorry, I meant Microsoft Outlook. And yes, it's the email client I'll be using to send the email. I know `R2HTML` plays nice with Microsoft, but I'm having difficulty getting it to include the `<HTML></HTML>` tags needed to have Outlook recognize it as HTML.

Comment: Is your only issue that it is missing the HTML tags? If so the following answer should work.  If not I will delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add the HTML tags to the saved file:

```
mytableout <-htmlTable(data)

sink("data.html")
cat("<head>")
print(mytableout,type="html",useViewer=TRUE)
cat("</head>")
sink()
```

Comment: Thank you!! Yeah the HTML tags was my only problem.